# Event for when PowerShell finishes a command?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to create a InputObject for The [Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-6).
The object needs to hold the event for when a PowerShell command finishes.
So if I type dir into PowerShell it gets registered with the Register-ObjectEvent.

I am having trouble finding the event for when powershell finishes a command, or if there is even one?

My code at the moment is just:

```
PS C:\>$CommandFinishWatcher  = /* Watches for a finished powershell command. */
PS C:\>register-objectEvent -InputObject $CommandFinishWatcher  -EventName "PowerShellCommandFinished"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the automatic variable $? to check the status of **the most recent command** that powershell ran. It contains the execution status of the last operation.

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html

```
Get-Content -path C:\Test
if($? = "FALSE")
{Write-Host "The get-content command failed."}
if($? = "TRUE")
{Write-Host "The get-content command succeeded."}
```

Comment: I'm looking to run a command every-time a power shell commad is run by the user.